# User unable to login salesforce from china location

Tags: salesforce, sar

User unable to login salesforce when he move to China from France. We suggested to try to connect through company network and we have added china IP ranges in user network access still he is not able to access the Salesforce. Can you please help here?

Comment: Due to Chinese regulations, we are not allowed to send traffic with our standard 205.204.x.x range IP address in-country. Within China we instead need to use a different IPs (180.169.205.13, 180.169.205.18, 180.169.205.19). We had to switch to this IP range relatively recently – you may have previously had a different China-only IP range in your whitelist. These three IPs will need to be added to the whitelist allowed to access SAR.

As per the request 
We have white-listed the mentioned IP's now
But user still facing an issue with Salesforce.